# How to set `underline` followed by a character to send another key

Tags: autohotkey

When I use the following , autohotkey says 'Error:Invalid hotkey". Is there any way to fix it?

```
_t::T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoHotkey has **Hotstrings** and **Hotkeys**.

**Hotstrings**

What you have there is a "Hotkey" (e.g. a key on keyboard). As there is no such key it is indeed an error. So what do you want, do you want to type _t followed by a space, tab or other Endcharacter and have it replaced by T? In that case it is `::_t::T` so you need to start the line with a `:`
More about Hotstrings and various options here https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm (you can have it send T without the need for typing an Endcharacter for example).

**Hotkeys**

If you want to press **_** and **t** at the same type and have it send T that is a Hotkey and you should us a Custom Combination by using **&** like so `_ & t::T`
More information on Hotkeys here https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

Comment: Thاnk you very much. Based on your information, `:*:_t::T` solves my problem.