# Using a hotstring and an hotkey at the same time

Tags: autohotkey

This question is related to [How to set `underline` followed by a character to send another key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48483509/).
I would like that `_t` produces `T` and `t` produces `s`. But using the following `_t` produces `_s`. Is there any way to fix it?

```
t::s
:*:_t::T
```

Answer (score 1):

The Computer can not see the differency between a **[hotstring t presses]** and a **[hotkey t presses]** the only thing what you can do is to do if _ is pressed [disable the hotkey] and then [enable enother t hotkey that send the Shift+t=T if the t is pressed] you can do that with the **[#if]** commands

try this AHK code.

```
; [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [^ = Ctrl] [# = Win] 
#SingleInstance force
mode=1

:*:_::
send _
mode=0
modes=1
return

#if mode
t::s
#if

#if modes
t::
send +t
mode=1
modes=0
return
#if
```

note - If you change the code a little bit, you can then also use a Hotstring in the modes for example: `:*:test???:: minus the Hotstring :*:_???::`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
:*:_t::T
t::SendRaw s
```

or with hotstrings

```
:*:_t::T
:*R:t::s
```

Oleg's comment below makes sense, add ? to the option(s) of the hotstring(s)

<strike>adding other keys</strike>

```
:*:_t::T
:*R:t::s

:*:a::a
:*:b::b
:*:c::c
:*:d::d
:*:e::e
:*:f::f
:*:g::g
:*:h::h
:*:i::i
:*:j::j
:*:k::k
:*:l::l
:*:m::m
:*:n::n
:*:o::o
:*:p::p
:*:q::q
:*:r::r
:*:u::u
:*:v::v
:*:w::w
:*:x::x
:*:y::y
:*:z::z
```

Comment: If I type `t` followed by `_t` then this `_t` does not type `T`. Is it possible to  fix this?

Comment: Thank you. I will check you solution and come back later.

Comment: Unfortunately if before typing `t` I type another character (say `g`) it does not work.

Comment: Adding more keys above, only problem remains s you can't type s t or _t as it isn't (yet) included in the list. What is it actually that you are doing?

Comment: @Name If you want the hotstring to triger anywhere just add `?` to it. `:?*:_t::T`